# Double for loop index issue

Tags: delphi, for-loop, matrix

I have been learning Delphi today and I am facing a strange error:

```
type
  TMatriz = array[1..10,1..10] of Integer;

var
  i, j: Integer;
  tablaDeMultiplicar: TMatriz;

begin
  for i := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    for j := 1 to 10 do
    begin
      tablaDeMultiplicar[i-1,j-1] := i*j;
    end;
  end;
  for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    for j := 0 to 9 do
    begin
      Write(tablaDeMultiplicar[i,j]:6);
    end;
    Writeln;
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

This, as far as I know, shold show the multiplication table. Right now it shows a row of 1 2 ... 9 0, the rest 0.

When I try to change the indexes from 1 and 10 to 0 and 9 and adjust the line accordly, it shows nothing. I tried another things and I only got it to work this way:

[image: Program working weirdly]

The only conclusion I get from here is that you can not operate with vars from a for :/

Comment: Tip: Activate range and overflow check during the development phase. That will catch these kind of errors quickly.

Comment: Did you see my answer? **I didn't say you should change `tablaDeMultiplicar` or `TMatriz`.** And next time, just copy the text from the console window and post it here. Simply format it as code. Do not post a photo of your screen. And look what I wrote exactly. You use for `I := 0 to 10` in your second set of loops. **But there is no index 0. It should be `1 to 10`!**

Comment: In other words: please do **exactly** what I wrote, and **do not program by trial and error**.

Comment: I'll better not write what the conclusion I get from this is.

Comment: Well Mr. White is not that easier when you have the program in your laptop and writting the post in your desktop computer.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Velthuis for your time. My problem simply was that I was expecting some kind of exception or error when I am trying to access tablaDeMultiplicar[0,0] when I am defining the matrix from 1 to 10. Since this error did not appear I thought my indexes were correct. I will mark your solution as the good one. I also got a conclusion about you though ;).

Comment: Exceptions don't have to happen. AVs generally only occur if you access memory that does not belong to your program, or nil. So you must have been accessing your own memory, even if it was not part of the array.

Comment: @Guillermo: I would have taken a screenshot on my laptop and either sent it to my main computer over the network, or if that didn't work, per email, or dropbox, or some such.

Comment: @Mr. Velthuis you are right, but since I already had the screenshot taken (I sent it to a friend) I just downloaded it on my desktop and used it. By the way, yesterday I did not edited the question, you can see it was a moderator or similar (Remy Lebeau). I just wrote it and went to sleep (It seems to me by your comments that you thought I changed  the question or uploaded the photo afterwards). In this case sorry for the missunderstanding. In any case you solved my problem so thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your indices are off by 1. Your `tablaDeMultiplicar` is declared as:

```
TMatriz = array[1..10,1..10] of Integer;
```

That has indices `[1..10, 1..10]`

But you access it with indices 0..9 and 0..9:

```
for i := 1 to 10 do
begin
  for j := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    tablaDeMultiplicar[i-1,j-1] := i*j;  // i-1 and j-1 are 0..9 each
```

Change this to:

```
    tablaDeMultiplicar[i,j] := i*j;
```

And change your second set of loops too. All in all:

```
{$R+}{$Q+}
type
  TMatriz = array[1..10, 1..10] of Integer;

var
  i, j: Integer;
  tablaDeMultiplicar: TMatriz;

begin
  for i := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    for j := 1 to 10 do
    begin
      tablaDeMultiplicar[i, j] := i * j;
    end;
  end;
  for i := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    for j := 1 to 10 do
    begin
      Write(tablaDeMultiplicar[i, j]:6);
    end;
    Writeln;
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

*Note: no `1..11` or `for 0 to 10 do` anywhere. `1` and `10` all the time, because that is how you declared `TMatriz`.*

That compiles and works as expected:

```
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
     2     4     6     8    10    12    14    16    18    20
     3     6     9    12    15    18    21    24    27    30
     4     8    12    16    20    24    28    32    36    40
     5    10    15    20    25    30    35    40    45    50
     6    12    18    24    30    36    42    48    54    60
     7    14    21    28    35    42    49    56    63    70
     8    16    24    32    40    48    56    64    72    80
     9    18    27    36    45    54    63    72    81    90
    10    20    30    40    50    60    70    80    90   100
```

---

And heed this tip by @LURD: *Activate range and overflow check during the development phase. That will catch these kind of errors quickly*.

Also, if you have such problems, try [to debug](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Overview_of_Debugging) your code. It is easier than you think.